# OndemandGrid Range and X-Range

Tags: dojo, dgrid

In Dojo Ondemand Grid,I can see two headers with same value.In my jsp page,I am currently using Range Header to get the start and End count and Querying the DB using that.

```
      Range : items=0-24
      X-Range : items=0-24
```

Can we use X-Range Header to get the start and End count instead of Range Header.What is the difference here?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a detail of dgrid, but rather of dojo/store/JsonRest.  IIRC the reason it sets both headers is because some versions of Opera don't allow you to set the Range header on an XHR.

So yes, the same information is sent in both headers - the standard Range header is the preferred one to use, if you don't need to support browsers that can't send it properly.